# instance internal prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

as someone said that instance internal prototype is a link to constructor prototype so as per this

```
 function foo(){}
 x=new foo()
 foo.prototype={};
 x instanceof foo//false (if instance internal prototype is a link to constructor prototype than it should have been replaced with replacing prototype) but
 x.constructor==foo//true why according to the above definition if internal prototype is a link to constructor prototype it should have been updated
```

Comment: An objects prototype applies to all instances of that object

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you don't have real classes. You create objects and later add it's methods and properties. So all instances of foo will have the methods/properties applied to foo, doesn't matter when they were added.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an object with the `new` keyword, the prototype is not *copied*, it is *linked* to. In chrome, firefox and safari (but this is nonstandard), the link is accessible through the `__proto__` property, so:

```
var x = new T();
console.log(x.__proto__ === T); // => true
```

what is being done internally is that when a property is accessed and it can't be found in the object, the javascript engine looks it up in the prototype object, which itself could have a prototype object.